# Numpy indexing in python

Tags: python, numpy, indexing

Here is the deal,

```
idx_arr = [0,3,5,7];
tgt_arr = [
[0,3,3,5,5,6,6],
[1,1,3,1,1,3,3],
[2,4,6,8,1,2,9]]
```

I want to make new array with bool type that would look like. I tried also with sets but numpy.ndarrays are unhashable types. New matrix would look like

```
final_arr = [
[t,t,t,t,t,f,f],
[f,f,t,f,f,t,t],
[f,f,f,f,f,f,f]]
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you please provide me some good papers for becoming very good in numpy arrays, because I saw how effiicient they are. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using base Python:

```
[[True if val in idx_arr else False for val in row] for row in tgt_arr]
```

Result:

```
[[True, True, True, True, True, False, False],
[False, False, True, False, False, True, True],
[False, False, False, False, False, False, False]]
```